# Globals fields empty after form errors

Tags: form, globals, plugin-sproutforms

I'm using global fields on a multi language site to get the appropriate content depending on the locales used. Sof far so good.

However on a form page (sproutforms) these globals empty out after the form is submitted while an (input) error occurred.

How to overcome this issue?

```
                {# FORM #}
            <section class="col-sm-6 col-md-6" style="padding-bottom: 40px;">

            {# Prepare our error macro #}
            {% macro errorList(errors) %}
                {# To display errors, you want to make sure errors exist, and then you can loop through and display them #}
                {% if errors %}
                    {% for error in errors %}
                        {{ error }}</br>
                    {% endfor %}
                {% endif %}
            {% endmacro %}

            {% from _self import errorList %}


            {# Check if we should display or form or thank you message #}
            {% if craft.request.getParam('message') == ('thank-you' or 'bedankt-voor-uw-aanvraag') %}

                {# Check for the last entry submitted #}
                {% set lastEntry = craft.sproutForms.lastEntry() %}

                {% if lastEntry %}

                    {# If the last entry exists, we can output any of the variables that were present in the form submission. #}

                    <div class="alert fade in">
                        <i class="fa fa-cloud-download alert-icon"></i>
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">×</button>
                        <p>Thanks <strong>{{ lastEntry.fullName }}</strong>! We'll be in touch soon! Did you know you can display any of the values that were submitted in the form?  Here's a list of all the values in the last form submission:</p>
                    </div>


                {% endif %}

            {% else %}

                <form id="contactform" class="form-box register-form contact-form" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">
                    {{ getCsrfInput() }}
                    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="sproutForms/entries/saveEntry">
                    <input type="hidden" name="handle" value="contact">
                    {% if craft.locale == 'en_us' %}
                    <input type="hidden" name="redirect" value="/en/contact?message=thank-you">
                    {% endif %}
                    {% if craft.locale == 'nl_nl' %}
                    <input type="hidden" name="redirect" value="/contact?message=bedankt-voor-uw-aanvraag">
                    {% endif %}

                    <h3 class="title">{{ formsAndButtons.contact }}</h3>
                    <div id="success"></div>

                    <label class="control-label" >{{ formsAndButtons.yourName }} <span class="required">*</span></label>
                    <input class="form-control"  type="text" id="textName" name="fields[fullName]" {%- if contact is defined %}value="{{ contact.fullName }}"{% endif -%}>
                    {% if contact is defined %}
                    <div class="error">
                        {{ errorList(contact.getErrors('fullName')) }}
                    </div>
                    {% endif %}

                    <label>{{ formsAndButtons.email }} <span class="required">*</span></label>
                    <input class="form-control" type="email" id="textEmail" name="fields[email]" {%- if contact is defined %}value="{{ contact.email }}"{% endif -%}>
                    {% if contact is defined %}
                    <div class="error">
                        {{ errorList(contact.getErrors('email')) }}
                    </div>
                    {% endif %}

                    <label>{{ formsAndButtons.telephone }} </label>
                    <input class="form-control"  type="text" id="textPhone" name="fields[phone]" {%- if contact is defined %}value="{{ contact.phone }}"{% endif -%}>
                    {% if contact is defined %}
                    <div class="error">
                        {{ errorList(contact.getErrors('phone')) }}
                    </div>
                    {% endif %}

                    <label>{{ formsAndButtons.comment }} <span class="required">*</span></label>
                    <textarea class="form-control" id="fields-message" name="fields[message]">{%- if contact is defined %}{{ contact.message }}{% endif -%}</textarea>
                    {% if contact is defined %}
                    <div class="error">
                        {{ errorList(contact.getErrors('message')) }}
                    </div>
                    {% endif %}

                    <div class="clearfix"></div>

                    <div class="buttons-box clearfix">
                        <input class="btn btn-default" type="submit" value="{{ login.submit }}">
                        <span class="required"><b>*</b> {{ login.requiredField }}</span>
                    </div>
                </form>

            {% endif %}
            </section>
```

Comment: Sounds like a Sprout Forms bug to me, no? Have you tried contacting them?

Answer (score 2):

**TL;DR**
This issue has been resolved and will be available in the next release of [Sprout Forms](http://sprout.barrelstrengthdesign.com/craft-plugins/forms) (0.8.4)

The issue was caused by our use of `context switching` for custom content tables in combination with `renderObjectTemplate()`, the latter of which initializes the `twig environment` and loads globals if not already loaded. This initialization is `context sensitive` so since we needed to switch context and then use `renderObjectTemplate()` before we could switch the `context` back, `globals` would inherit the content model from the form entry itself, not their actual content.

We fixed this issue by initializing the environment before any context switching is done.

[Selvin Ortiz](http://selv.in)
**Barrel Strength Design**